# Are there existing approaches to estimate inherent dynamics of an unknown system?

Tags: linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems

Consider a set of measured discrete-time signals $y_t \in \mathbb{R}^L$, which are captured from a dynamic physical system with underlying states $x_t \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Let's assume we have more sensors than relevant state variables, i.e., $N < L$, and that we have plenty of time-series data for $y_t$.

**My question is**: given only the time-series data for $y_t$ (and no other information about the system), are there any established methods for estimating state signals $x_t$ that:

1. capture all relevant system dynamics and
2. (optional) are physically meaningful/insightful?

#### One Possible Solution:

So far, what I've come up with is the following. First, we approximate the system as linear and write:
\begin{align}
x_{t+1} &= A x_t \\
y_t &= C x_t,
\end{align}
where $A$ is $(N \times N)$ and $C$ is $(L \times N)$, similar to the standard [state-space representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) of a linear dynamical system with no known inputs. We can then combine this system of equations as follows:
\begin{equation}
y_{t+1} = C x_{t+1} = C A x_t = C A C^+ y_t,
\end{equation}
where $(\cdot)^+$ denotes the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse). We can then estimate the matrix product, $M = C A C^+$, by constructing two time-shifted $y$ matrices and computing:
\begin{equation}
Y_2^T = M Y_1^{T-1} \implies Y_2^T \cdot \left(Y_1^{T-1}\right)^+ = M,
\end{equation}
where, given $j > i$,
\begin{equation}
Y_i^j = \begin{bmatrix} y_i & y_{i+1} & \cdots & y_{j-1} & y_j \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
This step appears similar to the approach taken in [dynamic mode decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_mode_decomposition). Note that at this point, $M$ is $(L \times L)$, so provided that we have at least $T = L + 1$ time samples of $y_t$, we can compute an overdetermined estimate of $M$.

Then, we can take a truncated [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) approach, where we write:
\begin{equation}
M = C A C^+ = U \Sigma V^*.
\end{equation}
Then, we factor $\Sigma$, which is square and diagonal, into two matrices and take the square root of each, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
M = \left( U \sqrt{\Sigma} \right) \left( \sqrt{\Sigma} V^* \right).
\end{equation}
We can then truncate the excess columns of the first $\sqrt{\Sigma}$ and the corresponding rows of the second, and write
\begin{align}
C &= U \sqrt{\Sigma}\\
A C^+ &= \sqrt{\Sigma} V^*,
\end{align}
where the $\sqrt{\Sigma}$ in the first equation is $(N \times L)$ and that in the second is $(L \times N)$. (The choice to have $A$ in the second equation rather than in the first was arbitrary.)

Thus, $A$ is given by
\begin{equation}
A = A C^+ C = \sqrt{\Sigma} V^* U \sqrt{\Sigma}.
\end{equation}

Now that we've solved for the update matrix $A = \sqrt{\Sigma} V^* U \sqrt{\Sigma}$ and the output matrix $C = U \sqrt{\Sigma}$, we can compute the state signals by
\begin{equation}
x_t = C^+ y_t.
\end{equation}

Assuming the truncated singular values were negligible, it would seem that we've arrived at a representation that captures all relevant system dynamics (my goal #1). But physical insight is rather unlikely, I'd imagine.

#### A Simpler Solution:

A more straightforward approach I've considered is to simply take the first $N$ [principal components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) of the data matrix $Y_1^T$ (as defined above). We can then call those the state variables, given by
\begin{equation}
W y_t = x_t,
\end{equation}
where $W$ is the PCA projection matrix truncated to $N$ components.

#### Another Alternative Solution:

Another approach I've taken is to use an [autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder), wherein the hidden variables give a reduced-order estimate of the system dynamics, but again, physical insight is unlikely.

#### Example of Desired Physical Insight:

My stated goal #2 is admittedly rather vague, so as an example, consider a system of [coupled oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation#Coupled_oscillations). In such a setup, the system naturally alternates between two distinct modes of operation, and the system overall usually exists in a superposition state between the two. Ideally, whatever reduced-order state representation results from an analysis of the measured data, I'd like such distinct operating modes to be evident. Perhaps this is not as unlikely as I anticipate, but neither does it seem to be guaranteed by either of the methods I described.

#### Restating the Question:

So, to reiterate my original question: are there any other, more elegant and/or general approaches to this problem? Ideally, ones that might even yield some physical insight?

If not, is it because what I'm asking is impossible? Are there additional assumptions that I would need to make to make the problem feasible?

Comment: Can you describe an example of physical insight you want to get ?

Comment: Thanks for the question @PiyushGrover I'll update the post to include an example.

Comment: Try looking up Takens’ Embedding Theorem. This theorem can be used in some situations to recreate the underlying dynamical system.

Comment: Once you have a $A$ and $C$ matrix you could always perform a similarly transformation, which can transform $x_t$ into something physically meaningful.